# Angular route not matching with hash

Tags: angular

I have these types of routes in angular 12

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInAuthGuard] },
  { path: 'register', component: RagisterComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInAuthGuard] },
  { path: 'pagenotfound', component: PagenotfoundComponent },
  { path: '404', component: PagenotfoundComponent },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' },

];
```

issue is i have several links on my sites with `href='#'` so when i click on those links i'm getting redirected to home page. Is there any way if i click on these blank links it should stay on that page only without being redirected. Thanks

Comment: why u have `href=#` when u don't want to nagivate or change the route ?

Comment: @YogendraR: For now i don't have to navigate but later on i will create these routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `href="javascript:void(0)"` on your `href` so it will stop the redirect or you can use `onclick="return false"`.

**Example 1**

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
```

**Example 2**

```html
<a href="" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of href="#" you should use

> routerLink

on your anchor tag. Using href causes that the whole page reload agian.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as most of the pages are not fully converted to angular routes is there anyway i can restrict redirection when using `href="#"`  for now